# Why does a Java constructor have to be public or protected for a class to be extended outside its package?

Tags: java, inheritance, constructor, default, access-modifiers

The following is my `ProtectedConstructor.java` source code:

```
package protectCon;

public class ProtectedConstructor{
    public int nothing;
    ProtectedConstructor(){
        nothing = 0;
    }
}
```

And following is the `UsingProtectedCon.java` source:

```
package other;

import protectcon.ProtectedConstructor;

public class UsingProtectedCon extends ProtectedConstructor{   //**Line 4**
    public static void main(String... a) {  
    }
}
```

When I compile `UsingProtectedCon.java`, I get error at Line 4 shown above. It says that ProtectedConstructor() is not public ; so cannot be accessed outside package.

However, since my class is public, shouldn't I be able to extend it outside package. I am anyway not creating any instance of it.

Now, if I make the constructor of `ProtectedConstructor` class as `public` or `protected` then the code compiles fine with no error.

So then why is it necessary even for the constructor to be `public` or `protected`, and not just have default access?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you want to extends a class outside its package it must have a constructor that is `public` or `protected` because in Java every constructor must call a constructor from its superclass.

Because of this there is an implied `super()` call in every constructor which does not have `this()` or an explicit call to `super()` as its first statement.  And if you don't specify a constructor at all Java will add a default parameterless constructor, so in effect your code looks like this:

```
public class UsingProtectedCon extends ProtectedConstructor {
    public UsingProtectedCon() {
        super();
    }

    public static void main(String... a) {   
    }
}
```

So in other words your code is failing to compile because the call to `super()` in the default constructor cannot be resolved.

Answer (score 3):

`constructor` is a member of class like `field` and `method` so access modifier applies to it [in the same manner it apples to all the member of class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2238730/what-is-the-difference-between-access-specifiers-and-access-modifiers)

when you extend the class A in B , A's its default constructor will get called from B's constructor implicitly (if you don't call any of the overloaded constructor)

Comment: Nitpicking: There are no overriden constructors in Java.

Answer (score 1):

in your class ProtectedConstructor is defined with Package-Private access
This means that outside the package its not seen even by the classes that extend from your ProtectedConstructor class

Define your constructor with 'protected' access modifier instead and you'll be done:

```
 package protectCon;

public class ProtectedConstructor{
    public int nothing;
    protected ProtectedConstructor(){
        nothing = 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your constructor is not public. Default scope is package-private.

Answer (score 0):

[JLS 6.6.7](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/names.html#6.6.7) answers your question. A subclass only access a protected members of its parent class, if it involves implementation of its parent. Therefore , you can not instantiate a parent object in a child class, if parent constructor is protected and it is in different package.Since the default constructor of the subclass would try to call parent class constructor ,you got this error.

See this [SO Post f](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5150748/protected-constructor-and-accessibility)or details

Answer (score 0):

to avoid all confusion do it like this.
   package protectCon;

```
public class ProtectedConstructor{
    public int nothing;
    public ProtectedConstructor(){
        nothing = 0;
    }
}


package other;

import protectCon.ProtectedConstructor;
public class UsingProtectedCon extends ProtectedConstructor{   //**Line 4**

    public UsingProtectedCon(){
      super();
      }


  public static void main(String... a){   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have constructors which are public, protected (for internal used) and even private.

A simple example is String which has `public` constructors for general use and package-local constructors for internal use.

The ObjectOutputStream class has a public constructor which takes an OutputStream and a `protected` constructor which can only be used by a sub-class.

BTW: if you have an `abstract` class, does it make sense to make the constructor `public` as if often the case. ;) hint: it is the same as `protected`.

Answer (score 0):

If child will have constructor which is private in parent,we can make child's instance with that constructor and cast it to parent's type.
So to prevent this java compiler is not allowing constructor to have constructor which is private in parent.